# como hago para salir de un bucle en java al digitar un numero

Tags: java, java-swing, condiciones

Espero puedan ayudarme. Estoy haciendo un modelo de cajero en java usando JOptionPane, la idea es que el usuario ingrese mediante un usuario y una contraseña preestablecidas y que tenga opciones de depositar dinero, retirar, consultar saldo, ver las todas las acciones realizadas (imprimir un mensaje con las acciones realizadas cronológicamente) y salir. Pero no he logrado hacer que cuando el usuario introduzca un 0 en el input para loguearse el programa finalice automáticamente.

De otra manera debe aparecer la ventana de opciones indefinidamente

Les Agradezco su ayuda de antemano

```
package cajero;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cajero {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int retirar, ingresar, total = 0, digito;


    String usuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Usuario"); // Al digitar un 0 aquí el programa debe finalizar
    String contrasenia = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Contraseña");

    String mensaje = null;

    if ("miuser".equals(usuario) && "pass".equals(contrasenia))  {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gracias por usar nuestro sistema");



    while (usuario !=0) {


     digito = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor ingrese que desea hacer: \n" + "1- Ingresar dinero \n " + "2- Retirar dinero \n " + "3- Consultar Saldo\n" + "4- Acciones realizadas: \n" + "5- Salir"));



        if(digito ==1) {

            ingresar = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor digite el valor a ingresar"));

            total += ingresar;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ud ha depositado:\n"  + ingresar + "El valor total es:\n" + total);
        }

        else if (digito == 2){

            retirar = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor digite cuanto desea retirar"));

        if ((retirar <= total) && (retirar > 0)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operación realizada satisfactoriamente");


        } else {

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dinero insufuciente");

        }}


        else if (digito == 3){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su saldo total es:\n " + total);

        }

        else if (digito == 4) {

         switch (digito) {
             case 1:
                 mensaje += "\n" + "1- Ingresar dinero" + "\n";
                 break;
             case 2:
                 mensaje += "\n" + "2- Retirar dinero" + "\n";
                 break;
             case 3:
                 mensaje += "\n" + "3- Consultar Saldo" + "\n";
                 break;
             case 4:
                 mensaje += "\n" + "4- Acciones realizadas" + "\n";
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Acciones Realizadas: \n" + mensaje);
        }
    }

    } else {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Incorrectos");
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que dice es: Mientras que 'usuario' sea diferente de 0, entonces que el bucle siga
Y pues la única manera de detener el bucle es que el usuario sea 0 y ya, pero el 'usuario' es un String, así que no permitirá números enteros, te recomiendo usar boolean
Ejemplo:

```
boolean status=false;
   while(status==false){
       //Tú code
       Y al final pongas: status=true;
}
```

Comment: El problema es que debe ser si o si un 0, no un valor booleano

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de hacerlo seria la siguiente:

Tenemos la variable *usuario* que es un `String`, y para que finalice tu programa lo tienes que comparar un `0`.

Debes comprobar que el usuario que introducimos sea un `0.` Nos ayudaremos de una función.

**Ejemplo:**

```
public static boolean isInteger(String usuario){
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(usuario);
        return true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }


if(isInteger(usuario){
    System.exit(0);
}
```